# Quartz.Net (2.2.3) Scheduling New Jobs

Tags: devexpress, quartz-scheduler

I am running the Quartz.Net server as a Windows service, like described in the documentation.  I am trying to understand how I can create new jobs for Quartz to schedule, without the need to rebuild the Quaretz.net server application everytime.

I would like to be able to add new jobs from an exe, dll, or other options welcome.  This way I can add jobs dynamically.  From what I can tell it seems all jobs must be defined up front and built into the server.  From there the user can pass parameters and enable triggers via XML file.  I am using MS SQL Server instead of XML file for persistence layer.

My use case is I need to generate reports at particular times, but the users can create new reports after launch of my application.  I am using Dev Express for my reporting (not sure if this matters).

Any guidance is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the work Tolis Bekiaris did on the [eXpand Framework's JobScheduler](http://apobekiaris.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/JobSceduler). It's a module for DevExpress's XAF and Quartz.NET which should give you plenty of sample code, especially if you are already using XPO for your data.

You can get [the source code here](http://www.expandframework.com/downloads/download.html).

Or alternatively, [it's on Github](https://github.com/expand/eXpand).

You'll find the job scheduler code in *eXpand/Xpand/Xpand.ExpressApp.Modules/JobScheduler*.

Comment: I will look into this.  Unfortunately I am using entity framework, devexpress is just for reporting at the moment.